# Runtime error SIGSEV in opencv2 HOG code

Tags: opencv, gradient, runtime-error, histogram, integral

I got this code Im working on, extracted from http://smsoftdev-solutions.blogspot.com/2009/08/integral-histogram-for-fast-calculation.html.

Currently im porting the code on that page to opencv2 c++ implementation, and this is what I have so far.

MAIN

---

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//CONSTANTES
#define PI 3.142

//FUNCIONES
vector<Mat> extractIntegralHist(Mat in, const int _nbins);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//Definicion de variables
    Mat frame;
    vector<Mat> integrals(9);
    namedWindow("main_video",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("temporal_window",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

//Inicializa la captura del video
    VideoCapture cap(0);
       if(!cap.isOpened()){
           return -1;
           cout << "No se puede capturar";
       }

//Loop principal
    while(1){
       cap >> frame;
       imshow("main_video",frame);
       waitKey(1);

       extractIntegralHist(frame, 9);

    }
    integrals.clear();
}
```

FUNCTION

---

```
//CALCULAR HISTOGRAMAS DE INTEGRALES
vector<Mat> extractIntegralHist(Mat in, const int _nbins){
    Mat in_gray;
    int x,y;
    float temp_gradient,temp_magnitude;
    namedWindow("temporal_window",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//Convierte la imagen a escala de grises y normaliza
    cvtColor(in,in_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(in_gray,in_gray);
//Calcula la derivada de la imagen en gris en direccion x,y utilizando sobel
    Mat xsobel, ysobel;
    Sobel(in_gray, xsobel, CV_32FC1, 1, 0, 1);
    Sobel(in_gray, ysobel, CV_32FC1, 0, 1, 1);
    in_gray.release();
//Crea la matriz de 9 imagenes contenedoras -- REVISAR ESTE CODIGO
    vector<Mat> bins(_nbins);
    for (int i = 0; i < _nbins ; i++) {
        bins[9] = Mat::zeros(in.size(),CV_32F);
    }
//Crea la matriz donde se guardaran las integrales de la imagen
    vector<Mat> integrals(_nbins);
    for (int i = 0; i < _nbins ; i++) {
        integrals[9] = Mat(Size(in_gray.cols+1,in_gray.rows+1),CV_64F);
    }
//Calcula los contenedores
    for(y=0;y<in.rows;y++){

        float* xSobelPtr = (float*) (xsobel.row(y).data);
        float* ySobelPtr = (float*) (ysobel.row(y).data);

        float** binsRowPtrs = new float *[_nbins];
        for (int i = 0; i < _nbins; i++){
            binsRowPtrs[i] = (float*) (bins[i].row(y).data);
        }
    //Para cada pixel en la fila los valores de magnitud y orientacion son calculados
        for(x=0;x<in.cols;x++){
            if(xSobelPtr==0){
                temp_gradient = ((atan(ySobelPtr[x]/(xSobelPtr[x]+0.00001)))*(180/PI)+90);
            }
            else{
                temp_gradient = ((atan(ySobelPtr[x]/xSobelPtr[x]))+(180/PI)+90);
            }
            temp_magnitude = sqrt((xSobelPtr[x] * xSobelPtr[x]) + (ySobelPtr[x] *       ySobelPtr[x]));
            float binStep = 180/ /*_nbins*/9;
                for (int i=1 ; i<=/*_nbins*/9 ; i++){
                    if (temp_gradient <= binStep*i){
                    binsRowPtrs[i-1][x] = temp_magnitude;
                    break;
                    }
                }
        }
     }

     for (int i = 0; i<_nbins;i++){
        integral(bins[i],integrals[i]);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i <_nbins ; i++){
        bins[i].release();
     }

    return integrals;
}
```

The program compiles, but when I run it, it just stops, the debugger shows me a SIGSEV error and shows line 61 and 38.

38 - extractIntegralHist(frame, 9);

61 - bins[9] = Mat::zeros(in.size(),CV_32F);

I havent been able to pinpoint the problem because everything seems fine to me, can you take a look to the code please?

Edit. Update. It appears the program stop when the function extractIntegralHist is run, allegedly on line 61 (of the function). Now, I know this is a memory handling exception but I just can't find what's wrong with it, furthermore I don't understand what the debugger is telling me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
bins[9] = Mat::zeros(in.size(),CV_32F);
```

is attempting to access the tenth (note the zero-indexing) element of `bins`. Since `_nbins` is passed in with a value of `9`, this is past the  vector's bounds. Also, if you use `.at()` instead of accessing elements using `[]`, this kind of error will throw an `out_of_range` exception which should be more helpful in diagnosing the problem.

To assign each element of the vector to a `cv::Mat` containing zeroes, consider changing your loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < _nbins ; i++) {
    bins[i] = Mat::zeros(in.size(),CV_32F);
}
```

Or more succinctly, remove the loop and replace your `bins` initialization with

```
vector<Mat> bins(_nbins, Mat::zeros(in.size(),CV_32F));
```

Note that you have the same problem in your initialization of `integrals`.

Comment: Thanks, I have already solved the question as this is old but now I have another issue with this very same code. I need it to perfom faster because as of now I'm getting 16FPS when I'm applying this code a QT GUI application, I'm calling it as a thread every milisecond. Is there any way I can improve the performance on this code? please check for bad programming or wasted resources.

Comment: That really should be a separate question. And on this site it's a good idea to accept answers that are correct, both to say thanks to the person who answered, and to indicate to others that a solution has been found. You can even post answers to your own questions (like in this case).

Comment: yeah sorry about that, I always accept the answers it slip past me. I'll make a new post, thanks.